# Why was this spam post locked and deleted twice by the Community bot?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, spam, specific-answer, locked-answers

Looking at [the revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/396417/revisions) of [some spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/396417/1081494), it was deleted and locked twice:

> [image]

Checking another spam post, that one was only locked and deleted once.

What caused this one to get deleted & locked twice in quick succession? Some type of multithreading bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, that must have been a race condition. Moderators can see the timestamps of flags in the timeline, and I see two spam flags cast at 06:29:07Z.

Both were the *third* flag while they were cast, but apparently both were stored and only then the number of flags was counted, the system saw four of them, causing the post to be locked and deleted.